# Direct sum proof of R4 by 2 subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that
$Sp\{(1,-2,-1,2),(1,0,-1,0),(0,2,1,0)\} \oplus \{(-a-b,a,b,0) | a,b \in R\} = R^4$

Well, let's **Denote** $$A = Sp\{(1,-2,-1,2),(1,0,-1,0),(0,2,1,0)\}$$

and $$ B = \{(-a-b,a,b,0) | a,b \in R\} $$

I need to show that: A,B are sub-spaces of $R^4$

and to show that: $A+B = R^4$ with a **single solution**. By putting their sum in a matrix and doing some elementary row operations to get that $R^4 \subseteq A+B$ , and obviously we already can see that $A+B \subseteq R^4$ which get us to $A + B = R^4 $ and because we'll get a single soluion we can say that $A \oplus B = R^4 $

But, how can I prove that A,B are sub-spaces of $R^4$ ?

I thought that I can say: It's obviously that A is a sub-space of $R^4$ because A spans $R^4$, and B, if we put a span to B we'll obviously get a vector in $R^4$ which means it also spans $R^4$ ( in it's x-y-z lines for e.g. because z=0). Excuse me for my bad math english, I study in another language math. Can I just put a span to B and then show $A \oplus Sp(B) = R^4 $ which is $A \oplus B = R^4 $ or am I missing something here and I can't prove at all?

Comment: To get a basis of $B$, the easiest is to substitute $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ for $(a,b)$. This will give you two vectors which span $B$.
Anyway, at first glance, it seems to me that $\dim A=3$ (i.e. the $3$ given vectors seem independent) and $\dim B=2$, whence we could not get $A\cap B=\{0\}$ in a $4$ dimensional space..

Comment: I can say that $B= \{(a(-1,1,0,0) +b(-1,0,1,0)\}$ which makes $B = Sp\{((-1,1,0,0),(-1,0,1,0)\}$ which makes it a sub-space of $R^4$, am I right? and btw, what did you try to prove with the dimensions, that it can't be a direct sum of $R^4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to show that $\Bbb R^4=U\oplus V$ where 
\begin{align*}
U &=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{(1,-2,-1,2),(1,0,-1,0),(0,2,1,0)\} \\
V &= \{(-a-b,a,b,0)\in\Bbb R^4:a,b\in\Bbb R\}
\end{align*}
First, note that every vector in $V$ may be written as
$$
(-a-b,a,b,0)=a(-1,1,0,0)+b(-1,0,1,0)
$$
so
$$
V=\Span\{(-1,1,0,0),(-1,0,1,0)\}
$$
Next, note that $\beta=\{(1,-2,-1,2),(1,0,-1,0),(0,2,1,0)\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $\Bbb R^4$ (check this!) so $\beta$ is a basis for $U$.

Now, note that $(1,0,-1,0)\in U\cap V$ but $(-1,1,0,0)\in U$ while $(-1,1,0,0)\notin V$ (check this!). This means
$$
U\cap V=\Span\{(1,0,-1,0)\}
$$
so we cannot write $\Bbb R^4=U\oplus V$.

It is true, however, that $\Bbb R^4=U+V$ since $\beta\cup\{(-1,1,0,0)\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^4$ (also check this!).

Comment: I tried to say that U = V, thus U - V = 0, put it on a matrix, and then get an answer, but I didn't get (1,0,-1,0)

Comment: But if I take scalar a = 1 and then a = -1, I'll see that $Sp\{(1,0,-1,0)\}$ is both in U and V

Comment: So, generally I can say that I see that (1,0,-1,0) in the intersection of U,V. and it's enough?also, if I want to prove mathematically I need to say that U-V =0 and put on a matrix?